# Is there any shortcut key to open vertical and horizontal guide line in photoshop cs5

Tags: photoshop

i am trying open new horizontal and vertical guide line in photoshop cs5. 1)  view -> New Guide -> Vertical this is for vertical guide line  2) view -> New Guide -> Horizontal this is for horizontal guide line. my doubt is, is there any other shortcut way to open these guide lines.

Comment: Its ctrl+alt+h for horizontal for me.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is not. However, you might be able to create your own hotkeys to select these menu items using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).